# react native n press click different screen not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-typescript

how to solve error 'undefined is not an object evaluating navigation.navigate' in react navigation 6 ?

```
const CategoryContainer = ({
  setSelectedItem,
  navigation,
}: {
  setSelectedItem: Function;
  navigation: any;
}) => {
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Filter')}>
      <Image
        style={Layout.icon}
        source={Images.ic_filter}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

})
```

Comment: Try to console log navigation, maybe you didn't pass it to your component.

Comment: Did you try using the `useNavigation` hook to access your navigation object instead?

Comment: @TomasGonzalez I've used useNavigation but there is an error like this 'Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?'

Comment: @AlijaFajić undefined in console log, how to pass navigation in component ?

Comment: Did you wrap your navigator in a navigator container? Can you upload the file where you initialize the navigator?

Comment: @TomasGonzalez <NavigationContainer theme={NavigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>

Comment: @AlijaFajić <Stack.Screen name="FilterOption" component={Filter} />

Comment: I gave you answer, try to use navigation like that.

Comment: if Alija Fajić  solution does not work then add your Navigation code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import navigation like this, I don't know what is problem at your case.

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

And than to use it like this:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```